# Java based RESTful Web service client

Tags: java, rest

I have come from Java based SOAP web service background and started working on REST. While I try to compare SOAP vs REST client, what confuses me most is that is it most common to call the RESRful web service directly from the browser? In SOAP, I used to generate the client in Java code, using the WSDL and hardly you call the SOAP WS directly from browser.
Also, I have seen Java based REST client code but not sure where does that fit most in the architecture. Appreciate any pointer on this.

Comment: Yes, RESTful services are way easier to "call" from anywhere, using any language, including from the browser using JS, which is probably where they're used the most. Single-page apps (written using Angular, React, etc.) typically rely on REST services called by the application written in JS and executing in the browser. That doesn't mean you can't call a web service from a Java client. It's just HTTP, and JSON/XML parsing. Still useful for B2B use-cases, or if you have a rich client app written in Java (like an Android app, for example)

Comment: It seems to be most common to call REST APIs from a browser, because that's the easiest way to test them, and to check if they are running. But in real life, they are used by whatever application or other service needs them, that may be a web app in a browser, some batch application, or other service as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it most common to call the RESTful web service directly from the
>   browser?

Yes, the consumer of the RESTful web services can be a Browser or any other application (which needs that data provided by the RESTful service).

RESTful web services return/exchange (in general) JSON data which seamlessly integrate with Browser applications as javascript (along with HTML) is mainly used for developing the Frontend layer (Views).

You can look at [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html)